# dev/KVM is not found

Tags: android, android-studio

I am using Linux mint 17 I installed android studio when I try to run the AVD I got the error below plc give me some help

KVM is required to run this AVD.
/dev/kvm is not found.

Enable VT-x in your BIOS security settings, ensure that your Linux distro has working KVM module.

Comment: Did you do as the error message says? Have you enabled KVM?

Comment: Probably not, because like me he might not understand what all these mean and is looking for some guidance from somebody who knows what they're doing.

Answer (score 0):

for the issue,you just need to reinstall HAXM is okay.

1. open the center of controller by type control.exe in cmd.exe.
2. Uninstall the HAXM
3. run the intelhaxm-android.exe and you can install HAXM again.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s07YU.png)